# Exit all threads in multithreaded program

Tags: c

I have a multithreaded program and in the code below, when the value of y becomes less than 0, I need all the threads to stop running.

Here's the source code -

```
     else if(y<0)
     {
             flag=1;
             printf("Exit the program\n");
             pthread_exit((void *)55);
             printf("sdjfajdflsdj");

            // return NULL;
     }
```

What is happening is that the program is printing the line - Exit the program, but gets stuck over there. It does not go to the line printf("sdjfajdflsdj"); and neither does it exit the code.

Can someone please help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pthread_exit` exits the current thread, not others.  I believe `exit` should exit all threads.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is the way that you're exiting the thread.

```
pthread_exit((void *)55);
```

doesn't pass a pointer to the value 55, it passes a pointer referencing 55 in memory, which isn't likely to be a readable address. Try:

```
int val = 55;
pthread_exit((void *)&val);
```